# css or javascript framework used by websites

Tags: javascript, css

How to know which css and javascript framework is used by a website.
Does websites hide it.
 Could not get any information on framework on checking the page source of website or web developer tool

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/library-detector/cgaocdmhkmfnkdkbnckgmpopcbpaaejo?hl=en

Comment: If you see `col-md-6` for example you can be fairly certain that they've used bootstrap, if you are familiar with other frameworks you will know, otherwise just look in google for class names, that can work.

Comment: Just open Firebug in Firefox or Javascript Developer Console in Chrome to analyze what comes in the network. jQuery.js or Angular.js or Bootstrap etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A website http://builtwith.com/ should give an answer to your questions - it'll also give you a good overview of statistics and usage.

Besides, using the tool you can explore more interesting and useful information about technologies, tools and frameworks that are being used.